# Is there an available and licensed version of strptime.h that will compile in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, strptime

I have looked at several implementations, and have not been successful at getting any of them to compile (with obvious modification) in Visual Studio 2010. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found one. My google-fu is improving.

http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/source/browse/trunk/src/common/timesupport.cc